# How to integrate pactflow.io with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, pact

I am new to pact and don't know how to integrate it with spring boot for contract testing. And also, how to get its libraries.
whether below dependencies to be used?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/au.com.dius.pact/consumer -->
<dependency>
<groupId>au.com.dius.pact</groupId>
 <artifactId>consumer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my PACT "bookmak".

I struggled the first time i tried using pact, so i hope it helps you.

Definition of Expand and Contract :
https://www.tim-ellhausen.de/papers/ExpandAndContract/ExpandAndContract.html

PACT Maven plugin to verify a provider :
https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/maven/

PACT Tags :
https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/tags/

PACT Versionning :
https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/versioning_in_the_pact_broker/

Recommended configuration for verifying pacts :
https://docs.pact.io/provider/recommended_configuration/#verification-triggered-by-provider-change

Recommended configuration for publishing pacts :
https://docs.pact.io/consumer/recommended_configuration/

Provider verification results :
https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/advanced_topics/provider_verification_results/#pacts-for-verification

Automate the contract and verification results exchange :
https://docs.pact.io/pact_nirvana/step_4/#e-configure-pact-to-be-verified-when-contract-changes

Can-I-deploy ? :
https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/can_i_deploy/

Publishing and retrieving pacts :
https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/publishing_and_retrieving_pacts/

Answer (score -1):

First Google result is this workshop: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-jvm-spring

There is also a maven workshop that also uses spring boot, see
https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/workshops/tutorials for all of them

Helpful?

Comment: Thanks Matthew, got bit of the idea from the provided links

Comment: No worries. Did you downvote my answer by any chance? Just wondering if it was useful, because the next person may not click the links if they see your question.